# Add Color Code Below Certain Value For Reviewing Hard Drive Space?

Tags: powershell

I am just wondering if there is a way to add color to results when below a certain value?

I run a script to pull drive sizes from servers, I would like to state a certain output value returned be a different color, so anything below 15GB be orange or something similar.

Is that even possible?

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Foreach ($server in $servers)
>> {
>>     $disks = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $server -Filter DriveType=3 |
>>         Select-Object DeviceID,
>>             @{'Name'='Size'; 'Expression'={[math]::truncate($_.size / 1GB)}},
>>             @{'Name'='Freespace'; 'Expression'={[math]::truncate($_.freespace / 1GB)}}
>>
>>     $server
>>
>>     foreach ($disk in $disks)
>>     {
>>         $disk.DeviceID + $disk.FreeSpace.ToString("N0") + "GB / " + $disk.Size.ToString("N0") + "GB"
>>
>>      }
>>  }
```

Please note I didn't write the script, I found it online.

Just to add to this, here is an example of my partial output:

```
RDS20
C:70GB / 119GB
RDS21
C:68GB / 119GB
RDS22
C:66GB / 119GB
RDS23
C:70GB / 119GB
RDS24
C:14GB / 119GB
RDS25
C:78GB / 129GB
```

Where RDS24 is showing 14GB I would like it to be a color that will stand out from the rest. So anything below 15GB be a different color.

Comment: Yes, you can make PowerShell output different colours.  What part of it are you having trouble with?

Comment: `Write-Host "Hello World!" -ForegroundColor Green`

Comment: Or ... a little crazier ... `Write-Host "Hello World!" -ForegroundColor Green -BackgroundColor Red`  ;-) :-D

Comment: I found $Highlight = @{ } but I am not sure what I would put for it to show me anything below 15GB freespace.

Comment: Where did you find it? I could imagine there's a little more behind it than just this.  ;-)

Comment: @Olaf No, I looked at the original but nothing about color coding. The code works just fine and gives me the output I need, I just want it where when it pulls 100 servers to give me an indicator showing anything below 15GB.

Comment: I meant where did you find this `$Highlight = @{ }`?  .... PowerShell does not have a an easy to use switch to use colors with different cmdlets. The only cmdlet I know of is `Write-Host`. The second solution would be to use escape sequenzes. Both would be a high effort for little benefit.

Comment: A *workaround* or *cheap version* could be to either sort the output for the value of the free space or to even filter the output for servers with disks with less than 15GB free space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple enough to do with write-host:

```
foreach ($disk in $disks) {
    # Set the output to a variable instead:
    $space = $disk.DeviceID + $disk.FreeSpace.ToString("N0") + "GB / " + $disk.Size.ToString("N0") + "GB"
    # if free space is less than 15 GB, make it red:
    if ($disk.Freespace -lt 15) {
        Write-Host $space -ForegroundColor Red
    }
    else {
        Write-Host $space
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
serverA
C:20GB / 99GB
D:112GB / 149GB
serverB
C:1GB / 99GB  ## This line is red
```

I personally prefer `[math]::round()` for disk size, but that's just preference.